# How to fetch the latest entry from the database table using LINQ (Asynchronous programming)

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

This is my current LINQ query to fetch the latest record from the table.

```
image = db.Images.ToList().OrderByDescending(e => e.ImageId).FirstOrDefault().ImagePath;
```

I am trying to integrate Async Await in my method but this query doesn't work with OrderBy.

Any alternatives to fetch the latest record from the table using LINQ with asynchronous programming?

Comment: It appears that most of this is being done client-side anyway (you pull the entire set of images from the database).

Comment: `var result = (await db.Images.OrderByDescending(e => e.ImageId).FirstOrDefaulAsync())?.ImagePath;`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.lastordefaultasync

Comment: Thanks it worked!